# search filter with a clickable list view

Tags: android-intent

i am creating an application with a search filter and a clickable list view. The search filter is working but not the clickable list view.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private ListView lv;

     ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

     EditText inputSearch;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        String products[] ={"1","1A","1B","1C","1D","2","2A","3","3A","3B","3C","3D","4A","4","5","5A","6","6A","6B","7","8","8B","9","10","10A","11","12","12A","13","13A","13D","14","14A","14B","15","15A","15C","15D","15F","16","16A","16D","17","17A","17B","17C","17D","17E","17F","18","19","20","20A","20B","20C","20D"};


        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
        inputSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputSearch);

        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, R.id.product_name, products);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);    


        inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                    int after) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                    int count) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                MainActivity.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(s); 
            }});




        //the code for clicking on the list view

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                          int position, long id) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                String routes =((TextView)view).getText().toString();

                 Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SingleListItem.class);
                  // sending data to new activity

                  i.putExtra("routes", routes);
                  startActivity(i);
                }});
            }
```

this is singlelistitem class

```
public class SingleListItem extends Activity{

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.setContentView(R.layout.single_list_item_view);

    TextView txtProduct = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.routes_lab);

    Intent i = getIntent();
    // getting attached intent data
    String product = i.getStringExtra("routes");

    txtProduct.setText(product);
```

Comment: In what way is the application 'not working'?

Comment: my application contain a list view and search filter. The search filter will search items from the list view and when clicking on a selected item it should give me additional on a different page. The problem is that after searching by clicking on the item the application stop working.

Answer (score 0):

As per your code i  am giving the following solution .

Note :Do some Modifications in your code.

```
Step 1:lv.setOnItemClickListener(this);

// lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view); add step 1 below of this in your code


Step 2:public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener
```

Step 3:Please let me know it is working or not so that i can help you

Comment: i have implemented the change but now the clickable list view is working but not the search filter

Comment: chsnge this code :  MainActivity.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(s);  to 
  
    String text = inputSearch.getText().toString();
    adapter.filter(text);

Comment: check with the following link also if you need for clarification:http://androidtrainningcenter.blogspot.in/2013/04/implementing-search-functionality.html